# Why does the button element allow vertical-align: middle?

Tags: css, button, vertical-alignment, css-tables

As far as I've been able to read, the `vertical-align: middle;` CSS attribute only works on elements with the `display` option set to `table-cell`.

**So why is `vertical-align` accepted on the `button` element? Have I missed something?**

The reason for my question is of cause that I want to mimic the `button` behaviour, to avoid using this structure:

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">Vertically aligned</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In most modern browsers, `vertical-align` also works on `inline-block` elements, such as `button`. Beware though that older browsers may not support this.

I think that it would be best for you to use an alternative way of vertically aligning your `div`. `vertical-align` on `inline-block` elements is commonly used just for, for example, aligning an icon with a string of text.

Answer (score 1):

According to the CSS 2.1 specification, the [`vertical-align` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) applies to “ inline-level and 'table-cell' elements”, and [inline-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-level) “ Inline-level elements are those elements of the source document that do not form new blocks of content; the content is distributed in lines (e.g., emphasized pieces of text within a paragraph, inline images, etc.). The following values of the 'display' property make an element inline-level: 'inline', 'inline-table', and 'inline-block'.”

The `button` element has `display: inline-block` in the [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html), and this corresponds to browser practice.

Thus, `vertical-align` applies to `button` elements.

Comment: So how come elements I apply the display type inline-block e.g.: the div tag, does not show this behaviour? http://jsfiddle.net/cK5cY/ do they have to own this value by default?

Comment: @DanielMierzwinski, that’s a different question (and your jsfiddle does not set `vertical-align` at all).

Comment: I see - I actually forgot to put that line in. Sorry about that! I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cK5cY/2/.
It might be a different question, but my point was that I wanted to avoid using the stated way of doing markup to achieve the middle aligned text. So that is the core of the question.

Nonetheless - I'm simply trying to make sense of why the button aligns the text inside in the middle on the vertical axis when the span and div tag ignores this.